# Is it better to learn one mussar Sefer at a time or a few?

Tags: mussar-ethics

Would it be advisable to learn Mesillas Yesharim, Shaarei Teshuvah, Tomer Devorah and Chovas Halevavos etc. every day?

Comment: Learning Mussar is about what works for that person. I would assume learning one sefer at a time for a longer period would work better though.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Binyomin and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Honestly same applies to Torah in general. Is it better to focus on one book in depth or learn many different subjects but maybe not as in depth?

Comment: See which one works for you / appeals to you.